# How do I chain several retrofit services with RxJava when I need the results of a previous one?

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit2, rx-java2

.

the puporse it to retrieve the details of inventories to do.
I have 2 services, one to get the availables inventories, an other one which gives you the details of a given inventory.

First have a look at my retrofit interface

```
public interface RetrofitApiService {

    @GET("inv.svc/availableInventories")
    Single<AvailableInventories> getAvailableInventories();

    @GET("inv.svc/inventoryDetails")
    Single<InventoryDetails> getInventoryDetails(@Query("invName") String invName);
}
```

Those are the object built by the retrofit services :

```
AvailableInventories
    List<InventoryName> inventoryNames

InventoryName
    String id
    String name
    String ref

InventoryDetails
    List<InventoryLine> inventoryLines

InventoryLine
    String articleRef
    String inventoryRef
    String conditioning
    String CountedStock
    String expectedStock
```

So I'm going to call `getAvailableInventories()` it will return a `AvailableInventories` object containing 3 `InventoryName` (for example)
First I want to store those `inventoryNames` in my_`database.Inventory_names`

```
InventoryName
    String "1"
    String "paris-warehouse"
    String "az2r8"

InventoryName
    String "2"
    String "mila-warehouse"
    String "d8f5s"

InventoryName
    String "3"
    String "berlin-warehouse"
    String "g8z3d"
```

then I will have to call

```
getInventoryDetails("az2r8")
    store in database, table inventory_line_details
getInventoryDetails("d8f5s")
    store in database, table inventory_line_details
getInventoryDetails("g8z3d")
    store in database, inventory_line_details
```

Finally I need to redirect to an other screen.

How can I do that in RxJava?
Previously I would have used simple android asynctasks and made them non-asynchronous using `.execute.get()`

However It seems that I cannot do that with rx java.

I will have to call the first service, then use something like `.iterate` or `.forEach` to call my `getInventoryDetails` services for each result

I'm quite lost.

isn't there a way for me to do something like this? :

```
compositeDisposable.add(simpleRetrofitService.getAvailableInventories()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(this::storeNamesToDatabse, this::logErrorAndDisplayPopup)); <-make it blocking and store AvailableInventories somewhere

for (InventoryName inventoryName : availableInventories) {
    compositeDisposable.add(simpleRetrofitService.getInventoryDetails()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(this::storeDetailsToDatabse, this::logErrorAndDisplayPopup)); <-make it blocking and store InventoryDetails somewhere
}

goToNextScreen()
```

Thanks.

Ps : as you can see java 8, streams and lambda is new for me

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can use `flatMap` and `zip` operators as follows:

```
compositeDisposable.add(simpleRetrofitService.getAvailableInventories()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .doOnSuccess(this::storeNamesToDatabse) // store names on success
    .flatMap(this::getInventoryDetails) // once availableInventories is fetched, proceed to get details 
    .subscribe(inventoryDetailsList -> { // we get a list of inventoryDetails
        this.storeDetailsToDatabse(inventoryDetailsList); // modify your function to use list of inventory details instead
        goToNextScreen(); // go to next screen when network calls finished
    }, this::logErrorAndDisplayPopup))
}
```

Where `getInventoryDetails(...)` returns another `Single` to be emitted downstream:

```
Single<List<InventoryDetails>> getInventoryDetails(AvailableInventories availableInventories) {
    List<Single<InventoryDetails>> singles = new ArrayList<>();
    for (InventoryName inventoryName : availableInventories) {
       singles.add(
           simpleRetrofitService.getInventoryDetails(inventoryName)
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
             .observeOn(Schedulers.io()
       );
    }
    return Single.zip(singles, inventoryDetailsList -> (List<InventoryDetails>) inventoryDetailsList); // here you might need to cast the result
}
```

Also, move your `goToNextScreen()` call within the subscribe callback to ensure that everything finishes before you leave the screen (as shown above).